# Display Twitter user profile without logging in?

Tags: java, android

I would like to display a twitter user profile without having the app prompt the phone user for creating an account or login information.

```
public void openTwitter(View view){

    try
    {
        // Check if the Twitter app is installed on the phone.
        getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.ProfileActivity");
        intent.putExtra("user_id", 01234567L);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        // If Twitter app is not installed, start browser.
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/xxx")));
    }
}
```

The code opens the twitter app and prompts the phone user for account creation before viewing profile xxx. I would like to simply view profile xxx without creating an account or logging in.

Comment: Define "profile", the profile of which user, do you want to display the profile website, a link to it?? What app prompts? Your app, the twitter app? Do you have an API key to talk to any twitter API?

Comment: I've updated my question to answer some of your quesitons. I do not have an API key to talk to any twitter API.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not going to happen, the twitter app does basically nothing without a logged in user. You *could* just view the profile inside your own app, without opening the twitter app.

Comment: That would work! The app I've been creating is a simple resume app and I just want the phone user to be able to view my twitter profile. How would I achieve this? Could you point me in a direction? Appreciate the replies.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to display anyone's profile, implement the Twitter API in your app and make the right REST calls and you should get the information you want to display.

If you want the user's profile specifically, there's literally no way around the user logging into their account with the API, unless they previously define their username in your app.

If you just want to display the profile and don't care about designing the information yourself, you could use a WebView to open the link to the profile you want to open, or use `UIApplication.shared.open` to open a link outside your own app.

Comment: I'm trying to be encouraging so they take more time to write a better question in the future? I don't see what your problem is, I layed out a way to improve and then tried to point them in the direction of a possible answer. You want to just completely leave them hanging when you could give them general pointers?